# what use the browsers to identify server session? Issue with CORS ajax losing JSESSIONID

Tags: cors, preflight

I'm accessing a tomcat server using CORS form other domain. I have several apps in server, and browsers (chrome, firefox) receive and use a different JSESSIONID on Set-cookie from server. The server use OPTIONS preflight to validate any CORS petition before to do the real GET or POST.
Everything is ok, each app has his own JSESSIONID and GET and POST works OK over server.
The problem is, I use a POST petition with a different url (another servlet) to upload files to server. When I do this petition, the browser don't do ever an OPTIONS preflight, and don't send the JSESSIONID to the server, so the server creates new session and send to client for this petition.
I've tried changing the upload servlet url to match the standard url used on all petitions, but with the same results, no JSESSIONID used.
I understand that a (java tomcat) web app can use several servlets/routes/urls and the browser must work as a unique app and use always the same JSESSIONID, but this is not the case.
Maybe change the standard application/json for 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' is why the browser don't use the same session, or maybe the problem is that CORS is involved.
By the way, I've tried to circunvent the problem taken care of the session id in my code, but the JSESSIONID is protected by the browser (HttpOnly), as configured on tomcat, so this is a no way.
Some guide on what the browsers use to identify and group petitions under the same session?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I've found the problem. On the client petition to upload file I forgot to use
        **withCredentials: true,**
on ajax options. Now JSESSIONID goes to server correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. On the client petition to upload file I forgot to use
        **withCredentials: true,**
on ajax options. Now JSESSIONID goes to server correctly.